# Spring component-scan not working? Mapped URL returns 404

Tags: spring, components

I am creating a Spring MVC webapp and I like to use automatic discovery of components such as controllers.

In my application-context file I put the following tag

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

There is a controller present in com.example.springmvc.controller

```
@Controller
public class AccountController  {

    @RequestMapping("/account.html")
    public ModelMap showAccount() throws Exception {

        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("someText", "This is an account");

        return modelMap;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/account.html")
    public ModelMap showAccount(@RequestParam("accountId") int accountId) throws Exception     {

        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("someText", String.format("This is an account with id %d", accountId));

        return modelMap;
    }

}
```

When I test by going to localhost:8080/account.html I get a 404, so I must be forgetting something.

When I create a custom mapping in my MVC config file, like below, than it works. At least, then I get an error about ambigious methods in the controller, but that is another problem. At least then it finds the controller.

```
<bean name="/account.html" class="com.example.springmvc.controller.AccountController"/>
```

I don't want to create my mappings in XML, I want to use annotated URL mappings. Could you tell me what I am forgetting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable annotation-based configuration scanning, add the following to your Spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this works.

Also, to annyone reading this: Make sure you've got a logging framework like log4j set up so you can see at application start what is going on. I ran into a "SEVERE: Error listenerStart" error when starting my app and I only found out what the problem was after I configured log4j. It seemed that I first didn't have the correct xsi:schemaLocation= values in my applicationcontext file, so it didn't properly load the mvc XSD. Secondly, I had a wrong method mapping in my controller which caused the application not to start properly.